# Combobox Binding MVVM WPF SelectedValue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

Having an issue getting the selected Value of a Combobox.  The error I get is and I cannot seem to fix it, have tried various combinations of binding, selectedvaluepath etc hopefully someone can point me in the right directions, thanks!

> ConvertBack cannot convert value 'ClientRatesWPF.Model.ChargeUnit'
>   (type 'ChargeUnit').
>   BindingExpression:Path=SelectedChargeUnitListValueId;
>   DataItem='ClientRatesViewModel' (HashCode=33434731); target element is
>   'ComboBox' (Name='cmbChargeUnit'); target property is 'SelectedValue'
>   (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException:
>   Int32Converter cannot convert from ClientRatesWPF.Model.ChargeUnit.

```
<av:ComboBox x:Name="cmbChargeUnit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="548,15,0,0" Width="187" ItemsSource="{av:Binding ChargeUnits}" DisplayMemberPath="ChargeUnitDescription" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedChargeUnitListValueId}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{av:DynamicResource {x:Static av:SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}" Height="20" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

VM:

```
public ObservableCollection<ChargeUnit> ChargeUnits
{
    get { return _chargeUnitsCollection; }
    set { _chargeUnitsCollection = value; }
}

public IList<ChargeUnit> ChargeUnitDescription
{
    get { return _chargeUnitDescription; }
    set
    {
        _chargeUnitDescription = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ChargeUnitDescription");
    }
}

public IList<ChargeUnit> ChargeUnitListValueId
{
    get { return _chargeUnitListValueId; }
    set
    {
        _chargeUnitListValueId = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ChargeUnitListValueId");
    }
}

public int SelectedChargeUnitListValueId
{
    get { return _SelectedChargeUnitListValueId; }
    set
    {
        _SelectedChargeUnitListValueId = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedChargeUnitListValueId");
    }
}
```

Where I am populating the Observable Collection (code extracted from method)

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    _chargeUnitsCollection.Add(new ChargeUnit
    {
        ChargeUnitListValueId = (int)reader["ListValueId"],
        ChargeUnitDescription = reader["ValueName"].ToString()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you have a combo box populated with a list of `ChargeUnit`'s and you are trying to set the `SelectedValue` to an `int` that will be your problem. You need to change to the selected `ChargeUnit`

```
public int SelectedChargeUnitListValueId
{
    get { return _SelectedChargeUnitListValueId; }
    set
    {
        _SelectedChargeUnitListValueId = value;
        var unitsWhere = ChargeUnits.Where(x => x.id == _SelectedChargeUnitListValueId);
        if (unitsWhere.Count() > 0)
        {
           SelectedChargeUnit = unitsWhere.First();
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedChargeUnitListValueId");
    }
}

public ChargeUnit SelectedChargeUnit
{
    get { return _SelectedChargeUnit; }
    set
    {
        _SelectedChargeUnit = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedChargeUnit");
    }
}
```

and in your binding:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedChargeUnit}"
```